# Impossible to add digits to the ArrayList despite using appropriate method

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, compiler-errors

I am currently implementing a binary calculator as a part of my course assignment for Java Programming. I have stumbled across one problem I don't understand. In the code outlined below, I wanted to make the program add '1' i '0' digits into the `ArrayList`, when asked so by hitting the appropriate button. Compiler says that it can't find the method add(int) - I have tried checking the internet, even asking my collegues from the university, and no one seems to have a solution.

However I initialize the ArrayList, either by

```
    List<Integer> binaryNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

or by

```
    ArrayList<Integer> binaryNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I am still getting the same error.

//Problem solved.

Comment: `static int[] binaryNumber;` are you *sure* your using a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: *"Here is the whole code."* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  It should take no more than 20 lines of code to set up the same compile error.

Comment: `static JPanel buttons_panel;`   BTW - `static` is rarely a solution to anything.

Comment: *"Let me answer you like that:"*  Don't add links to screenshots when asked for the text, type it out!

Comment: the usage of "static" has been forced by my compiler.

Comment: Here you are...
"cannot find symbol
 symbol: method add(int)
 location: variable binaryNumber of type int[]"

Comment: *"has been forced by my compiler."*  Then it's about time you figured out how to use the tools correctly.  Compilers do not 'force' anything.  If you mean the Netbeans compiler, you need to figure out how to use it correctly.

Comment: Adam the answer to your error has already been provided..

Comment: *"Here you are.."*  1) Edit it [into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16585093/edit) 2) Add @Zutty (or whoever) to ensure they are notified of a new comment.  The `@` is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare an array:

```
 static int[] binaryNumber;
```

Array doesn't have `add` function.

You can use List instead:

```
 static List<Integer> binaryNumber;
```